# Highlighting the selected item from list in angular

Tags: html, angular, list

I have an array of items which are retrieved from the database. This list changes constantly hence the list displayed on the html changes dynamically. I wish to highlight only the selected item from the list but the entire list is being highlighted upon selection.

The following is the HTML code in angular 2

```html
<div class="list-group " *ngFor="let year of years">
              
            <a routerLink="records" routerLinkActive="active" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                <mdb-icon fas icon="table" class="mr-3"></mdb-icon>{{year}}</a>
                
        </div>
```

[This is how the list is viewed upon selecting an item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5KUr.jpg)

Comment: if you move *ngFor in your 'a' tag?

Comment: @Beller  that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your model so that your object contains year id, title and year selected.
Then have an array of that years and on click make that year selected and delete others.
Then in ngCLass modify css and set active class with appropriate css like opacity, color etc.

```
<div class="list-group ">
<a *ngFor="let year of years" routerLink="records" routerLinkActive="active" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
  <mdb-icon (click)="setSelected(years, id)" fas icon="table" class="mr-3" [ngClass]="{ 'active': year?.selected }"></mdb-icon>{{year?.title}}</a>
 </div>
```

and the function will be:

```
    setSelected(years: Year[], id: number) {

    if (!years) {
    return;
    }

    this.years.map( year => {

      return {
       ...year,
       selected: (year.id === id)
      });
    }
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it what you are doing here - on every click you run through collection of year objects and for each year object you iterate over all fields in the object just to add `selected` field. It might be very slow if year object has many fields or `years` is a big collection. Much easier to do something like: ```setSelected(year) { if (this.selected) { this.selected.selected = false; } this.selected = year; this.selected.selected = true; }```